# Variable not working on scrollTop value inside .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, position, offset, scrolltop

Hi peeps wondering if anyone could help me with a click function, should animate to the target anchor which it does fine when using an integer for the scrollTop value however when I pass a variable it doesnt like it. Any ideas?

```
$(".project a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var full_url = this.href;
    var parts = full_url.split("#");
    var trgt = parts[1];
    var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();   
    var target_top = target_offset.top; //- 90; 

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 1000, function() {  
    });
});
```

**FIXED:** Ok apologies peeps the function was working fine from the get go however a colleague has pointed out var trgt contained an element that was set to display:none in the css, with the original intention of using slideToggle on callback... massive sigh. Cheers for your responses though!

Comment: No error as it stops you from scrolling during the "1000" duration as if it were actually working... really stumped :S

Comment: Means it doesnt starts scrolling at all?

Comment: It doesn't scroll at all. However if I replace `scrollTop:target_top` with `scrollTop:500` it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse variable to integer with

```
parseInt(target_top)
```

and try again. Let me know if not working my suggestion.

Or read this: [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/javascript-jquery-using-a-variable-in-the-css-property-of-animate). Look at `Andy E`'s answer.

Comment: typeof returns number on target_top, I tried parseInt anyway but no luck. Also tried Andy's method of assigning the variable as an object literal but again didnt work.

Comment: @SamuelDavidHardy: see the value of `target_top` with `console.log` in Chrome